# fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer

Tags: kde, git, plasma

```
vijay13@ubuntu:~$ git clone git://anongit.kde.org/plasma-mediacenter

Cloning into 'plasma-mediacenter'...

fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
```

Can someone please help me to get rid of above error ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're experiencing is caused by the host, it's  down, temporary o permanently.

You can try pinging anongit.kde.org and you'll see that is not responding.

If you don't have any particular reason for using that URL, take a look at this:

```
http://community.kde.org/Plasma/Plasma_Media_Center
```

They provide all the information you'd need.

The first stable release of the Plasma Media Center was release 4 months ago and the git for the code is

```
https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/multimedia/plasma-mediacenter/repository
```

Comment: thanks git clone http://anongit.kde.org/plasma-mediacenter worked :-)

Comment: Great, you worked it out on your own! =)